# Questions with Building a dapp using Quorum

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, dapps, quorum, permissioned-chain

I am working on a project to build a dapp for a trust system using Quorum, which needs a permissioned blockchain for data privacy. Only the admin, beneficiary, caregivers, case manager and authorized person can access the trust system. I am a beginner of blockchain and Ethereum and all those related things. Here are my questions so far:

1) I have tried to follow truffle Quorum tutorial. That quorum-examples includes the 7Nodes. What if I need more than 7 nodes? And I have no idea how I can use Quorum, not the quorum-examples, to build my dapp. Are there any tutorials not using the example?

2) The trust system involves a number of actors. They have to login before accessing the real system through the frontend website. Admin will be responsible for creating the trust and relevant accounts. How should I set the account of admin? Should I use admin as the owner of the trust system?

3) How should I save those username, password, etc., if I don't want them to be saved on the blockchain?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: 1) You should be able to use any number of nodes. 2) You should be able to create trust relationship with an smart contract. 3) In Ethereum all data is public, Quorum has privacy features. I can't recommend anything without more details of your use case.